# Discord.js A different js file for each command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Hello so I am learning javascript and can't figure out how to have multiple .js files for each command I have some code that I followed online however it does not seem to work for me (I am on discord.js v12.2)

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const fs = require('fs');
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
  client.user.setActivity("Type ~help for commands")
});

fs.readdir('./cmds', (err,files) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

    let cmdFiles = files.filter(f => f.split(".").pop() === "js");

    if (cmdFiles.length === 0){
        console.log("No files found");
        return;
    }

    cmdFiles.forEach((f,i) => {
        let props = require(`./cmds/${f}`);
        console.log(`${i+1}: ${f} loaded`);
        client.commands.set(props.help.name, props);
    })
})

client.on('message',msg => {
    if (msg.channel.type === "dm") return;
    if (msg.author.bot) return;
        if (msg.channel.type === "dm") return;
        if (msg.author.bot) return;
    
        let msg_array = msg.content.split(" ");
        let args1 = msg.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(' ');
        let args = msg_array.slice(1);
        let cmd = args1.shift().toLowerCase();
        let command = client.commands.get(cmd);
    
        if (!msg.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
    
        if (client.commands.has(cmd)) {
            command = client.commands.get(cmd);
                if (cmd){
                    command.run(client,msg,args,args1);
                }
    }
    
});

client.login(token);
```

The error message I am getting with this code is

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at C:\Users\rubyn\Desktop\AlexLearning\index.js:27:40
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\rubyn\Desktop\AlexLearning\index.js:24:14
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:164:23)
```

Thank you for taking time to read this :)

Answer (score -1):

You need to require all of your "cmds" first at the top. You can create an object with those "cmds" that you can later reference in the `forEach`. Have the key for each "cmd" in the object be the value of `${f}`;

UPDATE

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const fs = require('fs');
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');
// Require all your individual cmd files
const cmd1 = require(`./cmds/cmd1`);
const cmd2 = require(`./cmds/cmd2`);
const cmd3 = require(`./cmds/cmd3`);
const cmd4 = require(`./cmds/cmd4`);
// create an object to reference them later
const cmdObj = {
    cmd1,
    cmd2,
    cmd3,
    cmd4
};

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
  client.user.setActivity("Type ~help for commands")
});

fs.readdir('./cmds', (err,files) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

    let cmdFiles = files.filter(f => f.split(".").pop() === "js");

    if (cmdFiles.length === 0){
        console.log("No files found");
        return;
    }

    cmdFiles.forEach((f,i) => {
        // Dynamically reference an object property
        let props = cmdObj[f];
        console.log(`${i+1}: ${f} loaded`);
        client.commands.set(props.help.name, props);
    })
})

client.on('message',msg => {
    if (msg.channel.type === "dm") return;
    if (msg.author.bot) return;
        if (msg.channel.type === "dm") return;
        if (msg.author.bot) return;
    
        let msg_array = msg.content.split(" ");
        let args1 = msg.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(' ');
        let args = msg_array.slice(1);
        let cmd = args1.shift().toLowerCase();
        let command = client.commands.get(cmd);
    
        if (!msg.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
    
        if (client.commands.has(cmd)) {
            command = client.commands.get(cmd);
                if (cmd){
                    command.run(client,msg,args,args1);
                }
    }
    
});

client.login(token);
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you but do you know how I can write out what you just said in code?